# Issues with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState([])

React.useEffect (() => {   
  fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setQuery(data) 
          console.log(query);           
         handleChange(); 
        })
})
```

I have 2 issues:

1. when I console.log(query), it is empty.but console.log(data) shows the correct array, how?
2. handlechange() is getting executed before the fetch is complete, why?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: `data` is the response from the API and `query` is the empty array which will be updated asynchronously. That is why logging `query` immediately after calling `setQuery(...)` logs previous value of the `query` which is an empty array

Comment: Also note that you haven't passed a dependency array to `useEffect` hook which will lead to `useEffect` running after each render of your component which is probably not what you want. Pass an empty array as a second argument to make sure `useEffect` runs only once, after an initial render.

Comment: _handlechange() is getting executed before the fetch is complete_ - that can't happen in the code you have included in your question. As `handleChange()` function is called from inside a `then()` block and this `then()` block only executes after the `Promise` returned by `fetch()` has fulfilled, so `handleChange()` function can't possibly be called before `fetch` is complete.

Comment: yes, right. handleChange uses query

Comment: addind a dependency array sends the array into a loop (not sure why)  useRef works though!

Comment: add an empty dependency array if you want to execute the effect only once. You probably added `query` in the dependency array which will lead to infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You may not understand clearly how `useState` work. Check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

I have 2 issues:

1. when I console.log(query), it is empty.but console.log(data) shows the correct array, how?

> State query will be updated after component is re-called (re-render). So, console here will get old `query`.

2. handlechange() is getting executed before the fetch is complete, why?

> I think `handleChange` will be executed after fetch complete. But you case, may be you have use `un updated query` to use.
> You can use `useEffect` to trigger `handleChange`, It makes sure after `query` already has been updated. Example:

```
React.useEffect(() => handleChange(), [query]);
```

Comment: got the console.log part. but still unclear about the handleChange()..can't seem to make it work. As soon as my page loads, handleChange is getting executed...

Comment: Yes, because in first time, value change from `undefined` to empty array. You should also check `data query` in handleChange function.